# How to Apply for a Chilean Visa in Canberra, Australia

Tags: visas, australia, chile, embassies

I am a third country passport holder (Yes, we need visa to visit Chile) currently living in Canberra, Australia.

I'm planning to go to Chile for my vacations. (Tourism)
I don't have any contacts in Chile.

I have two options to apply for a visa.

1. Get an appointment with the Chilean Embassy in Canberra.
2. Apply for one Online.

There are problems with both approaches.

1. The embassy does not answer the phone for me to get an appointment. It goes into a mailbox. (I've left messages, and called several times, different days, on different times).
2. Online visa requires me to give details of a contact in Chile. (I'm going as a tourist, and don't know anyone).

What are my options?

P.S.
I have called the Consulate in Sydney, they do answer the phone. They told me that they issue visas at the embassy and advised me to call and make an appointment. I have also emailed them, with no reply yet.

Steps I'm considering:

1. Keep on calling the embassy, hoping they will pick up.
2. Try to get to know someone from Chile (couchsurfing) who might be willing to give their details.
3. Try to ask the consulates (either Sydney or Melbourne) to pass on a message. (Not sure how this would work).
4. Try to find someone who works at the embassy, through local community FB pages or something - and get someone to answer the phone. (I'd prefer not to go down this path)

I've never been in a similar situation before. It is quite strange, to be honest.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Would the contact info of a hotel you will stay at do the trick?

Comment: It may be enough to just supply the address and name of your first destination (e.g. hotel name, street, zip code and city name) as "contact". I travelled to Chile several times and always just filled in that field with the address of any place I would stay at. However, this may be different for you. If possible investigate or ask an official.

Comment: I ended up calling the ambassador's office and asking the secretary there to transfer the call to the consular section.

It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP:

> I ended up calling the ambassador's office and asking the secretary there to transfer the call to the consular section. It worked.